# How get view from 3 cameras in one screen - video for holographic pyramid

Tags: movie-clip-editor

Videos to holographic pyramids need specific montage.
I have videos from 3 angles of the animation and i need to combine them in one in the way like showed on the picture below.

[image]

Is Blender movie clip editor able to do it like this?
I can do it in program like Sony Vegas but I need to know if it is possible in Blender and how to do it.

Comment: I tried to do it, but i didn't find if it is possible. Changed to other free program: HitFilm

Comment: On SE sites, the answer section is reserved for answers. Sorry you didn't get one here.. Glad you found a way through..